# Excel Pivot Table: Adding single column in grouped pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Using a pivot table with this setup:

```
  Name    Amount         Total
        Jan  Feb  ...
  A      1    2            3
  B      2    1            3
  C      4    1            5
  D      3    3            6
Total   10    7            17
```

The data is coming from a table where each "Amount" has a specific date (ex 1/1/2016, or 2/4/2016), these dates are then grouped by month in the Pivot Table. This pivot table will be changing/months will be added, so its not a fixed size. I would like to end up with something like this:

```
  Name    Amount         Total   %
        Jan  Feb  ...
  A      1    2            3     17%
  B      2    1            3     17%
  C      4    1            5     29%
  D      3    3            6     35%
Total   10    7            17    100%
```

But when I try to do this by adding a percent column in the data source, or by using a Calculated Field, a % column appears for each Amount column. ex:

```
Name          Amount                 Total 
        Jan  %      Feb  %   ...
  A      1   5%      2   11%          17%
  B      2   11%     1   5%           17%
  C      4   23%     1   5%           29%
  D      3   17%     3   17%          35%
Total   10   58%     7   41%          100%
```

*Note that my Grand Total Field is automatically removed

Is there any way of achieving my desired result with no VBA, and no upkeep of pivot table (hiding/unhiding rows, adding a separate table at end of pivot table that will be deleted when new months are added)

I would also like to keep the automatic Grand Total field, however I can just manually create one in my source data. (Assuming I can figure out how to insert single columns in a pivot table)

Answer (score 0):

In your pivot table you need to turn off subtotals, this is on by default. The percentages after each month are subtotals, whilst the last column of percentages is called the grand total. The grand total is the one you want.

To turn off subtotals you need to go the design tab and click on the "Do not show subtotals" selection of the subtotals.

Comment: this does not at all answer what the user is asking

Comment: After turning off subtotals, nothing changed. It may be important to note that after adding the % field into my pivot table, the grand total column is removed.

Comment: Do you need the grand total amounts or just the percentages? Scott that was not useful feedback

Comment: I would like both, but if the automatic Grand Total field is automatically removed, I can just manually create one in my source data. (Assuming I can figure out how to insert single columns in a pivot table)

Comment: Sorry I think the best you can do is drag amount twice into your values box and set one to show as sum and the other to show as a % of grand total. This will give you the two grand totals you are after but will unfortunately show you % for each month too.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with formats and field names:

1. Drag twice "Amount" one in "Summarize values by" -> **Sum** the other "Show value as" -> **% of Grand Total**
2. Put a space `" "` and double space `"  "` as Field Names in the pivot table
3. `" "` use a space as a custom format for the values in [% Field]
4. For Total % use the usual percentage format

It will be annoying to play with formats when you refresh the table but it is a solution to avoid the fake column outside the pivot table.

[image]